# How autoplay top tracks in spotify?

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I have created a button and have onclick event on that. Now i want to play and pause my top track but cant play that. Anyone can help ?

```
      var sp = getSpotifyApi();
      var models = sp.require('$api/models');
      var myAwesomePlaylist = new models.Playlist("My Awesome Playlist");
      myAwesomePlaylist.add(models.player.track);
      myAwesomePlaylist.add("spotify:track:6PvpKM4BW48ic8cbM4Vxcg");
```

here is my code this is being adding the playlist but if I'm manipulating it, like

myAwesomePlaylist.play("spotify:track:6PvpKM4BW48ic8cbM4Vxcg");

It doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The playlist doesn't play — you need the `player` for that.

`models.player.play(track, playlist, 0);`

Or, if you just want to play/pause:

`models.player.playing = true;` / `models.player.playing = false;`

Documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/f19ff300f8.html). If this isn't what you meant, please be more clear with your question — the code you pasted in is copied straight from an example in the documentation.